# trigger function on specific time daily nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am Using Nodejs, and want trigger one function on 5:30 AM, 11:30 PM daily.

How should i follow that approach.

I also want to add more time apart from above like 9:45 PM, 5:30 PM

I have check https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule tried but not getting any luck.

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * 23 07 00', function () {
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
j.schedule()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it's a matter of luck, give a [mcve].

Comment: *tried but not getting any luck*.....that modules has 164,708 weekly downloads. It has nothing to do with luck, you're just doing something wrong. If you want an actual answer you're gonna have to be more specific

Comment: Hello Nikhil, I've voted to close your question as too broad. Please ask a more specific question, ideally including some of your code. See [ask]

Comment: ADDED the example

Comment: Great! Now whats the problem?Saying *Not having any luck* tells us nothing.

Comment: not sure how to trigger functions based on above time like `* * * 23 07 00` is 11:07 PM IST, but console didint apeard that time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have specified a wrong schedule pattern.

More readable way is using objects like this:

```
const j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 5, minute: 30}, () => {
  console.log('Job runs every day at 5:30AM');
});
```

And in case you need multiple Jobs running at different time of the day - create a few jobs with different time pattern and use the same function in each.

Comment: But this job will go away when scripts stop running or server restarts